# How to return a nonetype from a list of strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having trouble with this function. It doesn't work when I try to run it.
Can anyone help me fix it please?

```
def string_avg_update(L):
    '''(list of str) -> NoneType
    Given a list of strings where each string has the format:
    'name, grade, grade, grade, ...' update  the given
    list of strs to be a list of floats where each item
    is the average of the corresponding numbers in the
    string. Note this function does NOT RETURN the list.
    >>> L = ['Anna, 50, 92, 80', 'Bill, 60, 70', 'Cal, 98.5, 100, 95.5, 98']
    >>> string_avg_update(L)
    >>> L
    [74.0, 65.0, 98.0]
    '''
    average = 0
    for item in L:
        if item.isdigit():
            average = sum(item)/len(item)
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I'm not getting [74.0, 65.0, 98.0], which was what I want to get from the example in the docstring

Comment: Firstly, you need to split each of those string so you can extract the data from them. Then you need to convert the stuff after the name to floats. Then you can do arithmetic on those floats. And then you can save the result back into the appropriate list item. Trying writing some code that does those things.

Comment: BTW, you don't want `.isdigit()` for this. You know the format of those strings. There's no need to test if the grades are numbers, for the purpose of this assignment you can assume that they are.

Comment: Why all the down votes on this one? It's clear what the OP is trying to do and he/she made an attempt....

Comment: @kbball: There's no error description beyond "it doesn't work", and the question title demonstrates no understanding of what the task even is.

Comment: @user2357112 ok I see... I think SO is developing a reputation for being somewhat hostile to newbies and I just don't want to scare people off.. -3 from the outset is a little intimidating

Answer (score 0):

```
def string_avg_update(L):
    for x in range(len(L)):
        split = L[x].split(',')
        for y in range(1, len(split)):
            split[y] = float(split[y])
        summation = sum(split[z] for z in range(1, len(split)))
        average = summation/(len(split)-1)
        L[x] = average

L = ['Anna, 50, 92, 80', 'Bill, 60, 70', 'Cal, 98.5, 100, 95.5, 98']

string_avg_update(L)

print(L)
```

Returns:

```
[74.0, 65.0, 98.0]
```

After update:

Loop through L and create a new list, split, which splits the elements in L where there are commas. Then change the strings to floats where needed. Then run the summation and average on the floats. Set the element in L to the calculated average.

Comment: Is the for z in range statement in a new line?

Comment: I get the names for this one, when I run it , but I only want the averages

Comment: No the for z can be written just like that... The code works for me. Does your actual data not match what you have shown in L?

Comment: I want something like this >>> L = ['Anna, 50, 92, 80', 'Bill, 60, 70', 'Cal, 98.5, 100, 95.5, 98']
    >>> string_avg_update(L)
    >>> L
    [74.0, 65.0, 98.0] But it doesn't work for me. I mean the numbers after L

Comment: It also says there's an error when trying to test L

Comment: I just want the average of the numbers but I get the original thing

Comment: Copy and paste the code above in a stand alone session and let me know if you can replicate what I am getting. For me, it works just as you said

Comment: This isn't updating `L`. The function was supposed to update `L`.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Now that I understand what you're trying to do (with @PM 2Ring's help), here's a completely different answer (the problem is actually *much* simpler than I original thought).  It would have helpful if you responded to either my original answer or various comments from myself and others, and explained what you were trying to do more clearly...

```
def string_avg_update(L):
    '''(list of str) -> NoneType

    Given a list of strings where each string has the format:
    'name, grade, grade, grade, ...' update  the given
    list of strs to be a list of floats where each row
    is the average of the corresponding numbers in the
    string. Note this function does NOT RETURN the list.

    >>> L = ['Anna, 50, 92, 80', 'Bill, 60, 70', 'Cal, 98.5, 100, 95.5, 98']
    >>> string_avg_update(L)
    >>> L
    [74.0, 65.0, 98.0]
    '''
    # Replace contents of L with average of numeric values in each string elem.
    for i, record in enumerate(L):
        grades = [float(grade) for grade in record.split(',')[1:]]
        L[i] = sum(grades) / len(grades)

    # Function will implicitly return None since there's no return statement.

if __name__ == '__main__':

    L = ['Anna, 50, 92, 80', 'Bill, 60, 70', 'Cal, 98.5, 100, 95.5, 98']
    print(L)
    string_avg_update(L)
    print(L)  # -> [74.0, 65.0, 98.0]
```

Comment: What does  zip mean? like what does it do?

Comment: It's [right here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) in the  [online documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/index.html). In a nutshell it takes two or more lists and generates (`yield`s) groups (tuples) of elements extracted from the same position in each of the items in each of its input argument sequences. i.e. `zip([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])` returns an iterable the yields `(1, 4)`, `(2, 5)`, then `(3, 6)` sucessively. If you wrap it in a `list()` constructor call, you'll end up with a list containing `[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]`.

Comment: dg123: Does that answer your question about `zip()`? Is my answer producing the correct results? If not, please edit your question and describe how the values wanted are calculated from the input values.

Comment: Why are you finding the means of the columns? You just need the mean of each row.

Comment: @PM2Ring: Thanks. I finally figured out how the OP gets the values by reading your answer. Much simpler problem than doing what's currently in my own. Feel a little foolish for not realizing it myself, but they could have cleared things up earlier on by adding a single sentence to their question...

Answer (score 0):

We loop over the list using `enumerate`. This gives us the index of each list item (`idx`) and the string itself (`student`).

Then we call split on each string to extract its contents, saving the first item as `name`, and the rest as `data`. Then we convert the strings in `data` to floats. Then we compute the average of those floats. And then we save the average back into the appropriate list item.

```
def string_avg_update(L):
    '''(list of str) -> NoneType
    Given a list of strings where each string has the format:
    'name, grade, grade, grade, ...' update  the given
    list of strs to be a list of floats where each item
    is the average of the corresponding numbers in the
    string. Note this function does NOT RETURN the list.
    >>> L = ['Anna, 50, 92, 80', 'Bill, 60, 70', 'Cal, 98.5, 100, 95.5, 98']
    >>> string_avg_update(L)
    >>> L
    [74.0, 65.0, 98.0]
    '''
    for idx, student in enumerate(L):
        name, *data = student.split(',')
        data = [float(u) for u in data]
        L[idx] = sum(data) / len(data)

L = ['Anna, 50, 92, 80', 'Bill, 60, 70', 'Cal, 98.5, 100, 95.5, 98']
print(L)

string_avg_update(L)
print(L)
```

**output**

```
['Anna, 50, 92, 80', 'Bill, 60, 70', 'Cal, 98.5, 100, 95.5, 98']
[74.0, 65.0, 98.0]
```

Comment: What does enumerate mean

Comment: @dg123 "`enumerate` ... gives us the index of each list item (`idx`) and the string itself (`student`)". Please see https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate And in future, you should try to find the answer to such questions by searching the docs. If you don't understand what the docs are saying, _then_ ask here, quoting  the docs in your question, so that people know you aren't just being lazy.

Comment: Ya, I'll be sure to check that out next time, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
def string_avg_update(lst):

    for i in range(len(lst[:])):
        grades = lst[i].split(',')[1:]
        float_grades = [float(grade) for grade in grades]        
        average = sum(float_grades) / len(float_grades)        
        lst[i] = average



L = ['Anna, 50, 92, 80', 'Bill, 60, 70', 'Cal, 98.5, 100, 95.5, 98']
string_avg_update(L)    

>>> print(L)
[74.0, 65.0, 98.0]
```

I know `enumerate()` works better for this.

Comment: The function was supposed to mutate the input list, not make a new one.

Comment: @user2357112, oh, sorry I didn't notice that :) Changed the code accordingly.